# Fedora updating each time I run a dnf command

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora, dnf

I have been using Fedora for a while, and I noticed something. Each time I run a `dnf` command such as `sudo dnf install app-pkg` or even if `sudo dnf remove app-pkg`. It first downloads a set of Updates like Fedora x86_64, Fedora Modular x86_64, and a few other updates. Hence, it consumes a lot of time and internet while I use dnf commands.

Is there a way to prevent it from auto-downloading/updating?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dnf -C` to run from the cache, which will prevent this — or set `cacheonly` in the DNF configuration file. You can also set `metadata_expire` to a higher value — the default is 48 hours, or when a dnf configuation or repo file changes (check `check_config_file_age` to turn this off).

These options are detailed in `man dnf.conf`.